# How to mark bad-sectors on SSD drive?

Tags: ssd, dd, bad-sectors, bad-blocks

My SSD drive has started to have some bad sectors. My plan is to  to copy it to another drive using [dd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dd_%28Unix%29), but it seems like a few bad sectors are making this impossible.

How do I  mark bad sectors on the SSD so that dd can be able to copy the drive to another one?

I'm using the NTFS filesystem.

Comment: An SSD drive has no bad sectors. Read once more about flash memory and error correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to mark bad sectors manually. Hard disks have a pool of spare, good sectors. When bad sectors are found they are automatically flagged and replaced by spare, good ones. All this is invisible to the user.

FYI, you can use tools like Crystaldiskinfo and HD tune to monitor bad sectors, if the drive is SMART enabled (most drives are). However, please also run a hdd diagnostic (depending on your hdd brand).

[Harddrive diagnostic Tools and services - Tacktech.com](http://www.tacktech.com/display.cfm?ttid=287)

A few bad sectors are normal after a period of use. You should backup critical data from that disk on a priority basis. Unless the bad sector count is extremely high, keep a watch over it, particularly for sudden increases. When that happens, be prepared to order a new drive.

Comment: uh why did someone down vote this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about ssd hard disk but it's not everything automated. I was able to reallocate bad sectors and/or permanently marked them as bad and also using S.M.A.R.T. from the hard disk with SATA2 drive with this instructions: http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/badblockhowto.html. When you have some time I would try this first before anything else.

Edit: Updated url:https://www.smartmontools.org/wiki/BadBlockHowto

Answer (score 1):

Try using `dd_rescue` which skips over bad sectors instead of dying on error.

Comment: `dd_rescue` is obsolete. Use [`ddrescue`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ddrescue) instead.